# how can customize my UserDetailsSerivce implementation class for login user by phone and email

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

how can customize my `UserDetailsSerivce` implementation class for login user by phone and email both in spring bot below the my code.
is there any pattern matching required?
User can login both phone and email.

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    //user can login both email and phone

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username));
        } else {
            return JwtUserFactory.create(user);
        }
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User findByPhone(long phone);
}
```

Comment: someone please reply

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this?:

```
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
Optional<User> findByPhone(String phone);

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String input) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    return userRepo.findByEmail(input)
            .map(user -> new User(
                    user.getName(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    user.getRoles()))
            .orElse(userRepo.findByPhone(input)
                    .map(user -> new User(
                            user.getName(),
                            user.getPassword(),
                            user.getRoles())
                    ).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!"))
            );
}
```

---

Another approach - check input with [regex](http://emailregex.com/), if we've found an email then use `findByEmail` or else - `findByPhone`.

Comment: Cepr0 thanx for reply but how can i find out user input is phone or email based on that i have to call findByEmail(String email);
or findByPhone(long phone);

Comment: it's not necessary with my code - if user will be not found with `findByEmail(input)` then it try to find user with `findByPhone(input)` else - throw an exception..